# Drawing linear fit in matlab with semilogy

Tags: matlab

I m trying to make a liner fit from this dots. I have used lsline and in example it works perfectly well.

```
    x = 1:10;
y1 = x + randn(1,10);
scatter(x,y1,25,'b','*')
hold on;
lsline;
```

But when it comes to my function it does not work.

```
 X = [0.5762
0.6191
0.6594
0.6997
0.7359
0.7753]

N = [10 * 0.000001;
40 * 0.000001;
160 * 0.000001;
640 * 0.000001;
2560 * 0.000001;
10240 * 0.000001]

figure(1);
semilogy(X,N,'r*');
hold on;
lsline;
```

I have also tried the same X,Y,N but with

```
scatter(X,N,25,'b','*')
set(gca,'yscale','log')


lsline;
```

And it still does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `lsline` is for linear fit, not exponential. You need to take the logarithm of `N` to make a linear fit. In this case, I use the base 4 because your data look like `4^X`:

```
X = [0.5762 0.6191 0.6594 0.6997 0.7359 0.7753];
N = [10 40 160 640 2560 10240] * 0.000001;

figure;
plot(X, log(N)/log(4), 'r*');
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Log(N)')
grid on, grid minor
hold on
lsline;
hold off
```